# Problems with linking. Clang++

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++

I am new to clang as I was using msvc before but I want my project to be cross-platform. When I try to build my project, the linker cant link with glfw for some reason.

I get a couple more errors like this for other functions.

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol glfwInit referenced in function main`

Project Structure:

[image: Project Structure]

Build.bat:

@echo off

```
set headerFiles=-Ilibs/headers -Isrc
set libraryFiles=-Llibs/lib/glfw3
set cppFiles=src/*.cpp
set outPutName=LearningVulkan

call clang++ %cppFiles% %headerFiles% %libraryFiles% -o bin/%outPutName%.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging I found that I have to put the file path with -L and then use -l for the actual library name.

Here's what I mean

```
@echo off

set headerFiles=-I libs/headers -Isrc
rem add the file path with -L and then add the library with -l
set libraryFiles=-Llibs/libs -lopengl32 -lglfw3
set cppFiles=src/*.cpp
set outPutName=LearningVulkan

call clang++ %cppFiles% -DMD %headerFiles% %libraryFiles% -o bin/%outPutName%.exe

start bin/%outPutName%.exe
```